# Laravel, bringing an array to view

Tags: php, laravel

```
        $vegetables = DB::select("select a.id, a.created_at, a.updated_at,a.storeid, a.itemno, a.type, a.vegie from stores a, storenames b where a.storeid = b.storeid");
        return view('stores', ['vegetables' => $vegetables]);
```

I used the code above to query the DB and I got the following error in the view page:

```
 @foreach($vegetables as $vegetable)
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $vegetable['storeid'] }}</th>
                <td>{{ $vegetable['itemno'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $vegetable['type'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $vegetable['vegie'] }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add table name in query

Comment: you missing table name i think

Comment: You are wrong, he use a table: `from stores a`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco, have tried that before, but it doesn't work

Comment: What does your view look look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to cast the stdClass Objects as Array so you can have the structure you are looking for

```
$vegetables = array_map(function ($value) {
    return (array)$value;
}, $vegetables);
```

Comment: Call to a member function toArray() on array

Comment: Have you tried without `toArray()` like a Collection?